# TypeError: g[b] is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I am trying to pass down the coding value to datetimepicker in order to disable the specific day using "daysOfTheWeekDisabled". The problem is I get TypeError: g[b] is undefined as an error when I check the console. What could be the problem?

Here's the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#VehicleIDDD').change(function () {
            var vehdrv = ($('#VehicleIDDD :selected').val());                              
            var val = vehdrv.split("_");
            var drvid = val[1];
            var vehid = val[0];

            if (drvid == "0") {              
                $("#DriverID > option").each(function () {
                    $(this).show();
                });
            }
            else {
                //console.log(vehid + "= with driver " + drvid);
                $("#DriverID > option").each(function () {
                    var option_val = $(this).val();
                    if (option_val != drvid) {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }                       
                });
            }
            $("#DriverID").val(drvid)
            $("#VehicleID").val(vehid);


            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("checkCodingDay", "Reservation")',
                data: { "VehicleID": vehid },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var coding = data[0].CodingDay
                    daysOfWeekDisabled(coding);                   
                },
                error: function (emp) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });

        }).trigger("change");
    })

    function daysOfWeekDisabled(coding) {
        $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
          daysOfWeekDisabled: coding,                         
        });
        $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker('refresh');       

    }

</script>
```

If you need more details just comment down and I'll add what you're looking for.

UPDATE
[image: TypeError: g[b]]

[image: coding value]

[image: coding value 2]

Comment: can you print entire error and also what is the value of coding

Comment: Where is `g[b]`? I don't see everywhere in example code, in which line the error actually thrown?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it's actually from the browser's console, I added an image to show how it looks like.

Comment: @cdoshi coding's value is dependent on the vehicleID and the error appears on the browser's console, I added the image to show how it looks like.

Comment: I picked up the minified datepicker source from [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js) and not found anything matched with `g[b]` object. Can you provide value of `coding` after `var coding = data[0].CodingDay;` statement?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I added an image again. The value above the error is coding's value, since it's dynamic I tried to change variable to a fixed value and I still get the same error.

Comment: @Joshua what are the values that coding can take. Provide few samples by printing the values of coding

Comment: @cdoshi added an image which shows an alert whenever I choose an item from the dropdown which will give a coding's value.